# Remove block inside layout/xml from custom.phtml?

Tags: footer

I need to remove a block that is set by the `page.xml` the rwd folder / default / layout. The code of one of them is this:

```
        <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Footer</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
            </block>
```

In my research, I saw that it is possible to remove by creating a file called `local.xml` within the layout, but I have an option to hide/ visible within my module and must be removed through my file `custom.PHTML`, how as I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marius is right. You need to use `local.xml` for this kind of operation. In my opinion and based on my experience, this is what we need to do by `local.xml` file. Means it is a special layout update file which is used to remove unwanted blocks and block settings (means give a new action to a block). So use it wisely.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove layout handles from phtml files. The template files are interpreted after the layout xmls are loaded.